# file copying to multiple linux server using ansible get failed on parameter checksum

Tags: linux, ubuntu, server, ansible

I am trying to copy file to the Linux servers Using Ansible

Put the IP, username, password of the Linux servers in `/etc/ansible/hosts`

```
[servers]
server1 ansible_host=10.1.12.525 ansible_user=sun ansible_ssh_pass=lB7oG
server2 ansible_host=10.1.12.55 ansible_connection=ssh ansible_user=sun ansible_ssh_pass=l
```

IP pinging is successful.

Server copy command with checksum parameter got success but file was not present in server.

```
root@nithin-virtual-machine:/# ansible servers -m copy -a "src=./copy_module.txt dest=/tmp/"

server1 | SUCCESS => {
    "changed": true,
```

When added parameter checksum it shows following error:

```
root@nithin-virtual-machine:/# ansible servers -m copy -a "checksum=SHA1 src=./copy_module22.txt dest=/tmp/"

server1 | FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "checksum": "64277314ebb19680f67ef0ac4cede5c3db883b11",
    "expected_checksum": "SHA1",
    "msg": "Copied file does not match the expected checksum. Transfer failed."
}
```

Tried a lot, can't find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

The `checksum` parameter of the [copy module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/copy_module.html) takes the actual SHA1 checksum of the file and not the checksum algorithm `SHA1`. Note that the error is quite accurate, `checksum` is an actual SHA1 checksum, whereas `expected_checksum` is `SHA1` so it doesn't match.

*Also if you skip this parameter, Ansible will still use its own checksum from the source file.*

> If this is not provided, ansible will use the local calculated checksum of the src file.

To copy a file with `checksum` parameter, the correct way is:

1. Note down the checksum of the file, example `r.txt`:

   ```
   $ sha1sum r.txt
   663eca7fa8a326aab7299b2c11f3d97bbb34637b  r.txt
   ```
2. Use Ansible `copy` module to copy the file by specifying the above checksum:

   ```
   $ ansible localhost -m copy -a "src=r.txt dest=/tmp checksum=663eca7fa8a326aab7299b2c11f3d97bbb34637b"
   ```

**So the command you need to run is (using checksum from error message):**

```
ansible servers -m copy -a "src=./copy_module22.txt dest=/tmp/ checksum=64277314ebb19680f67ef0ac4cede5c3db883b11"
```